# display one category group in channel entry

Tags: categories

I want to display an entry's category, but only from a specific category group.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="paintings" limit="10"}
{title}
{categories group_id="42"}{category_name}{/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If I just use: {categories}{category_name}{/categories} I get all categories but I only want categories display if they are in group 42.  If they have nothing in group 42 I want nothing to display

Answer (score 2):

{categories show_group="42"}{category_name}{/categories}

Comment: Based on the docs, that SHOULD output only the categories within the group with ID 42 that the current entry is assigned to, as you described.